# DateDiff between MyDate and System date

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get result in TimeDiff column in my table where I have run DataMacro on TimeDiff column. 
DataDiff is between MyDate and System date and time.

```
DateDiff("hh";[MyDate];Now())+(Format(Now();"dd\.mm\.yyyy hh:nn";2;1)<Format([MyDate];"dd\.mm\.yyyy hh:nn";2;1))
```

I would like to have hours stored in my TimeDiff column, but keep getting an error. Could you please help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is `+(Format ...` supposed to do?

Comment: Also, why `<…`? Why not just save the Now() value and calculate difference in query?

Comment: I need that calculation to run VBA code on a field which will set departure date for customer. If the hours is bigger than 48 than VBA code will be executed.

Comment: Your "formula" makes absolutely no sense - adding time and text, and comparing numeric with text. You will have to explain what you are trying to do - and provide some sample data and expected output - which probably should be in a query and not the table.

Comment: I've got result I wanted. Just removed one h from formula and got result in hours. I have to type format 01.06.2020. 14:30 in my text field.